# Search bar in table view not finding any results

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I cant find results using my search bar. See my code attached:

```
// ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize names;
@synthesize keys;


#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sortednames"ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.names = dict;

    NSArray *array = [[names allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    self.keys = array;

     [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [keys count];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *nameSection = [names objectForKey:key];
    return [nameSection count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *nameSection = [names objectForKey:key];

    static NSString *SectionsTableIdentifier = @"SectionsTableIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             SectionsTableIdentifier ];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                       reuseIdentifier: SectionsTableIdentifier ];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [nameSection objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    return key;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBzJZ.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktevQ.png

```
here is my "h" file:



//
    //  ViewController.h
    //  Sections
    //
    //  Created by t r on 3/17/12.
    //  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController 
        <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>
    {
        NSDictionary *names;
        NSArray *keys;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *names;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *keys;
    @end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UIsearchBar does not automatically do a search on the tabelview content. You have to implement the UISearchbarDelegate methods to detect the entered text, then reload the table view and return values in the table view delegate methods according to the new array filtered with the search criteria.

Comment: I suggest that you have just on NSArray propery `NSArray *keysAndValues` .Each element of this array, should contain a dictionary, having two keys - nameKey(NSString) and nameArray(NSArray). In the delegate methods to return number of rows in section and cell for row at index path, use a sub array created by filtering the nameArray as per your search criteria